# Объекты в JS - не могу понять их имена

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, алгоритм, json

Запрос Ajax делаю так:

```
$("document").ready(function() {
    $(".js-ajax-php-json").submit(function() {
        var data = {
            "action": "test"
        };

        data = $(this).serialize() + "&" + $.param(data);

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            dataType: "json",
            url: "response.php", //Relative or absolute path to response.php file
            data: data,
            success: function(data) {
                $(".the-return").html(
                    "Favorite beverage: " + data["favorite_beverage"] + "<br />Favorite restaurant: " + data["favorite_restaurant"] + "<br />Gender: " + data["gender"] + "<br />" + data["some"] + "<br />JSON: " + data["json"]);
            }
        });
        return false;
    });
});
```

Что это за объекты var data = {"action": "test"}; и зачем их ассоциировать ?

Comment: Используйте отступ в четыре пробела или кнопку `{}` для оформления кода.

Comment: это дополнительные данные, кроме тех которые вы сериализировали из формы.

Comment: по поводу оформления учту

Comment: jean-claude зачем эти данные ?

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 1):

Хм, а спросить автора кода нельзя?

Он, видимо, использовал в разработке дополнительные поля для отладки:
Сделаю свой `AJAX-wrapper`, с проверками и неявной подстановкой `CSRF-токена`! Хотя зачем мне проверки?

Всё зависит откуда этот код взят, сейчас лишь можно предположить что это подменяет стандартное действие на сервере и продакшене это поле лучше убрать.

Answer (score 1):

На самом деле сериализация не нужна. Jquery может работать и с объектом. Суть функции `serialize()` в том, что она превращает объект в строку. Например `{'foo' : 'bar', 'ping' : 'pong'}` в `'foo=bar&ping=pong'`. `data = {"action": "test"}` - это дополнительный объект, который добавляется к общему, расширяя его какими-то опциональными значениями.

В данной ситуации {"action": "test"} вряд ли для чего-то нужен и скорее всего написан от балды, но вы можете добавлять туда свои значения, если у вас есть какой-то собственный API.